# Balance sheet from using yfinance does not have 'Total Debt' like on Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, yfinance

I am trying to use yfinance to access the 'Total Debt' row of a company in order to calculate the Effective Interest Rate, but it just won't show up when using .balancesheet, or .balance_sheet, or .get_balance_sheet on the created ticker object.

For example, here is the balance sheet of 'AAPL' on yahoo finance:
[image]

But if I use yfinance, I wouldn't see 'Total Debt':

```
import yfinance as yf
ticker_object = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
balancesheet = ticker_object.balancesheet
print(balancesheet)
```

'Total Debt' row is no where to be seen.
[image]

(I know that the full table isn't captured, I have a small screen, but you can trust me that it is not there)

Another work around I found is that I can just take the 'Short Long Term Debt' and then add 'Long Term Debt' from the table, but there are two problems:

- For companies like MSFT, if you do that, it wouldn't add up to the 'Total Debt' displayed on Yahoo Finance.
- For some companies like SNOW, or FB, the 'Short Long Term Debt' and 'Long Term Debt' rows would not even appear when using yfinance.

Therefore, I think being able to access the 'Total Debt' row from the table on Yahoo Finance is the quickest way to solve this issue. It's just that I cannot find it using yfinance.

I am also aware that there is a 'Total Debt' key in the dictionary when using .info on the ticker object, but that is the most recent quarter value and not the annual value that I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I made a simple function to grep data from finance.yahoo.com directly

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_balance_sheet_from_yfinance_web(ticker):
    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/balance-sheet?p={ticker}"
    header = {'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Expires': '-1',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) \
                AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'
                }
        
    r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    html = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'D(tbhg)'})
    if len(div) < 1:
        print("Fail to retrieve table column header")
        exit(0)

    col = []
    for h in div[0].find_all('span'):
        text = h.get_text()
        if text != "Breakdown":
            col.append( datetime.strptime(text, "%m/%d/%Y") )
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)
    for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-test': 'fin-row'}):
        i = 0
        idx = ""
        val = []
        for h in div.find_all('span'):
            if i == 0:
                idx = h.get_text()
            else:
                num = int(h.get_text().replace(",", "")) * 1000
                val.append( num )
            i += 1
        row = pd.DataFrame([val], columns=col, index=[idx] )
        df = df.append(row)

    return df
```

Here is the output

```
print( get_balance_sheet_from_yfinance_web("GOOG") )
```

```
                                           2021-12-31    2020-12-31    2019-12-31    2018-12-31
Total Assets                             359268000000  319616000000  275909000000  232792000000
Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest  107633000000   97072000000   74467000000   55164000000
Total Equity Gross Minority Interest     251635000000  222544000000  201442000000  177628000000
Total Capitalization                     264479000000  236476000000  205400000000  181578000000
Common Stock Equity                      251635000000  222544000000  201442000000  177628000000
Capital Lease Obligations                 15551000000   12840000000   12009000000      62000000
Net Tangible Assets                      227262000000  199924000000  178839000000  157520000000
Working Capital                          123889000000  117462000000  107357000000  101056000000
Invested Capital                         264479000000  236476000000  205400000000  181578000000
Tangible Book Value                      227262000000  199924000000  178839000000  157520000000
Total Debt                                28395000000   26772000000   15967000000    4012000000
Share Issued                                662121000     675222000     688335000     695556000
Ordinary Shares Number                      662121000     675222000     688335000     695556000
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Yahoo Finance v3/statistics, under the financialData section, there is a 'totalDeb' row.
Probably the difference you have is due to Leasing obligations which are considered in the totalDebt. However if your intention is to calculate de effective interest rate, yo should only consider the 'Short Long Term Debt' and 'Long Term Debt' rows.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience and understanding, Balance sheet is not like income statement where it needs to be added up for TTM. Thus, the current quarterly view of the balance sheet is where the firm stands today. So that total debt value is as of reported date.

Comment: I also checked again and for some symbols, the number is not accurate. I emailed Ran about it. thanks