# Parsing Yahoo Finance with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This question is a follow up on another question ([Web Scraping Yahoo Finance Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76459687/web-scraping-yahoo-finance-python)). When looking at the Yahoo Finance website for the income statement, balance sheet, and cash flow there is a button for the quarterly report but I am not sure how to access it: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL I want to return the Quarterly Report, how can I parse the website to return the quarterly report that is shown when that button is clicked on the website.

```
def get_balance_sheet(ticker):
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/balance-sheet?p={ticker}'
    soup = get_soup(url.format(ticker=ticker))

    table = soup.select_one('.BdT')
    all_data = []
    for row in table.select('.D\(tbr\)'):
        data = [cell.text for cell in row.select('.Ta\(c\), .Ta\(start\)')]
        all_data.append(data)

    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data[1:], columns=all_data[0])
    return df
```

This is the Annual Report returned

```
    Breakdown   9/30/2022   9/30/2021   9/30/2020   9/30/2019
0   Total Assets    352,755,000 351,002,000 323,888,000 338,516,000
1   Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest 302,083,000 287,912,000 258,549,000 248,028,000
2   Total Equity Gross Minority Interest    50,672,000  63,090,000  65,339,000  90,488,000
3   Total Capitalization    149,631,000 172,196,000 164,006,000 182,295,000
4   Common Stock Equity 50,672,000  63,090,000  65,339,000  90,488,000
5   Net Tangible Assets 50,672,000  63,090,000  65,339,000  90,488,000
6   Working Capital -18,577,000 9,355,000   38,321,000  57,101,000
7   Invested Capital    170,741,000 187,809,000 177,775,000 198,535,000
8   Tangible Book Value 50,672,000  63,090,000  65,339,000  90,488,000
9   Total Debt  120,069,000 124,719,000 112,436,000 108,047,000
10  Net Debt    96,423,000  89,779,000  74,420,000  59,203,000
11  Share Issued    15,943,425  16,426,786  16,976,763  17,772,944
12  Ordinary Shares Number  15,943,425  16,426,786  16,976,763  17,772,944
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are coming in from the wrong approach. Try the code below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame
import itertools
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="

tckr = ['MSFT','AAPL','AMZN']
        
i = 1

url_list = [(s, url_base + s) for s in tckr]
data_list = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

for t, url in url_list:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    print(t, url)
    print('Scrapping ticker {}...'.format(t))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    #writer.writerow([t])
    l = []
    for row in soup.select('.snapshot-table2 tr'):
        l.append([td.text for td in row.select('td')])
        x = list(chain.from_iterable(l))
        d = dict(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))
        d['Index'] = t
        
    data_list.append(d)
```

To explain the code a little: you loop through tickers in a list named 'tckr'. You can add whatever tickers you want to the list. Then, you get detailed financial metrics related to each ticker.